# How do I use {{ item }} in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to replicate the first with_item example from ansible docs, but I'm facing this error:

```
fatal: [user@my-vm]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'path/ansible/playbooks/android-dev.yml': line 4,
column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n
The offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Debugging with items\n      ^ here\n"}
```

My code is:

```
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - name: Debugging with items
      debug:
        msg: "An item: {{ item }}"
        with_items:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
```

I'm following the first example of this page to build the task: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/items.html

I've started using ansible now and it may be a simple issue to fix, but I really can't find any solution online

Comment: your with_items needs to be under debug not msg with YAML position matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is wrong. Fix it

```yaml
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - name: Debugging with items
      debug:
        msg: "An item: {{ item }}"
      loop:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
```

Use [*loop*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) instead of *with_items*.

Comment: Please add quotes around strings

Comment: Which strings are you talking about?

Comment: At least `name` but I think `hosts` too

Comment: Why should it be quoted? Is there any reference to support your reasoning?  Btw. expansion of msg in the example does not have to be quoted either.

Comment: Because it's cheap way of avoiding certain issues with your YAML. See official docs about that https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas

Comment: Not the case here. Right? Instead, one might argue [remove the quotes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2) from `msg`.

Comment: I don't agree. It's a bad habit to quote strings when not necessary. At first glance at the code, a quoted string is telling me "be careful, special characters are here".